# My banner code initially displays as expected, but after being closed, it should reappear automatically after one minute. However, it's not doing so?

Tags: reactjs

Here is my code for displaying the banner. Initially, it displays, but once closed, I have set it to reappear after one minute automatically. However, the banner is not setting up after the time. If someone could help me with this, it would be really helpful. Here is my code.If somebody could help it would be really appreciated:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { IoMdClose } from 'react-icons/io';

type PopupBannerProps = {
  onClose: () => void;
};

const PopupBanner: React.FC<PopupBannerProps> = ({ onClose }) => {
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(true);
  const [isScrolling, setIsScrolling] = useState(false);
  const [bannerType, setBannerType] = useState<'A' | 'B'>('A');
  const articleIds = [
    '8c31-r-c2', '5teta56ik08', 'a5q4r1cuyztq', '91aypylhsnp', 'rna7t_tn0', 'v1nyl6vr4l32',
    'qj64ls5nc', '94rc-epdqe', 'xu2d16nuw', 'nv63-ckx7n', '7t6la6-sm4a', 'whgly_sax67k',
    'flplvw-jb', 'yjhbblmv_7i', 'jetbhefvqf4', '3qmk4buyky', 'bjlfnr-8t1fx', 'kl-8rlvv5',
    'kztbtiqc6vr', 'op0ua0tsn1', 'oh4--clha', 'alsnyte1pr', 'eg_jwcf4llm', 'j5i25kfrj',
    'i12x202gyl', 'dm83n_pcs5w', 's-7sq0y_tgaz', '8vjdfprbk', 'wdodm02sacr6', '20oyjoserivv',
    '44f5zcr85cs', '9fhs3uina7c', '9mwdbjydytlc', '1e25p0nek', 'onk9l-b1uhl', 'vcslqj05f9'
  ];

  const addBanner = () => {
    const currentPageUrl = window.location.href;
    console.log(currentPageUrl,"************************8");
    
    if (articleIds.some(id => currentPageUrl.includes(`articles/${id}`))) {
      setBannerType('B');
    } else {
      console.log(".............................");
      setBannerType('A');
    }
  };

  const checkBannerStatus = () => {
    const isBannerClosed = localStorage.getItem('popupBannerClosed');
    if (isBannerClosed === 'true') {
      setIsVisible(false);
    }

    const lastClosedTime = localStorage.getItem('popupClosedTime');
    if (lastClosedTime) {
      const currentTime = new Date().getTime();
      const threeHours = 1 * 60 * 1000;
      const timeDifference = currentTime - parseInt(lastClosedTime, 10);
      if (timeDifference < threeHours) {
        onClose();
        setIsVisible(false);
        console.log("-------------");
        
      } else {
        localStorage.setItem('popupBannerClosed', 'false');
        localStorage.removeItem('popupClosedTime')
        const isBannerClosed = localStorage.getItem('popupBannerClosed');
          if (isBannerClosed === 'false') {
            setIsVisible(true);
            addBanner();
          }
        console.log("============= >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ================");   
      }
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    checkBannerStatus();
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      checkBannerStatus();
       addBanner();
    }, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(intervalId); // Cleanup function to clear the interval
  }, [addBanner]);

  useEffect(() => {
    let prevScrollY = window.pageYOffset;

    const handleScroll = () => {
      const currentScrollY = window.pageYOffset;
      const isScrollingUp = currentScrollY < prevScrollY;

      setIsScrolling(true);
      setTimeout(() => setIsScrolling(false), 500);

      prevScrollY = currentScrollY;
    };

    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    };
  }, []);

  const handleImageClick = () => {
    window.location.href = 'https://iot.dxhub.co.jp/lp';
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setIsVisible(false);
    onClose();
    localStorage.setItem('popupBannerClosed', 'true');
    const currentTime = new Date().getTime();
    localStorage.setItem('popupClosedTime', currentTime.toString());
    

    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      checkBannerStatus();
    }, 5000);

    return () => clearInterval(intervalId)
  };

  const bannerSrc = `/Banner ${bannerType}.png`;

  return (
    <div className={`popup-banner ${isVisible ? '' : 'fade-out'} ${isScrolling ? 'fade-out' : ''}`}>
      <a href="https://iot.dxhub.co.jp/lp" onClick={handleImageClick}>
        <img src={bannerSrc} alt="Banner" />
      </a>
      <button className="close-button" onClick={handleClose}>
        <IoMdClose />
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default PopupBanner;
```

Comment: Please, provide what kind of code you are passing as onClose prop to the PopupBanner component. Show us how you manage the local storage in the code, which is connected to the functionality.